# Processing previously uploaded files with subsequent removal

Tags: php

**Problem:** When filling out the form I need to be able to upload multiple files and after it when I submit the form to make the processing of all downloaded files.

On the client side to asynchronous file uploading I use a hidden iframe (because of IE7 support requirement). After successfully file upload I add information about this file to the form (its `$_FILES["file"]["name"]` and `$_FILES["application_add_file"]["tmp_name"]`).

When the form is submited I recieve array of the files like:

```
files[0][file_path]:/tmp/phpR8eHLx
files[1][file_path]:/tmp/phpDVh3Aw
```

How can I get these files for processing?

I tried `file_get_contents($_POST['files'][0]['file_path'])` but it's expected returns an error

```
Warning: file_get_contents(/tmp/phpR8eHLx): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I know that I can use `move_uploaded_file()` on each file upload, but if I do so how I can handle situation when user upload some files but do not submit the form? As I understand those uploaded files will remain on my server and I need to somehow remove them manually (and as i guess in the tmp directory files deleted after a while automatically).

**Update**: I dynamically add `<input type="file">` to the form and submit all files at once. I want to convert uploaded files to base64 and send it to another server. Should I use `move_uploaded_file()` (for safety reasons?) or I can just work with it in a tmp dir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to `move_uploaded_file()` on each file upload, store those in an upload directory and wait for the form submit.

Then you can set up a cron job on the server to monitor the old files, so if some user doesn't submit the form, the job will clean it up after a predefined time.

I also suggest that you don't send the server path of these files back to the client, instead you can store them server side, either on [Session](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) or in the Database.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I think about it, but is it a best solution? Maybe I underestimate the difficulty of the task, but this solution looks too cumbersome.

Comment: Do you have to upload the files before filling out the rest of the form? You could change it to send it all at once. There is one library I like, Plupload, maybe it can help, it has nice features like chunked uploads, progress tracking, etc.

Comment: If you must ask for the files before asking the rest of the form, you could change your client-side to a wizard-like form, where you show the file inputs first, then hide it, show the rest of the fields, and last submit it all at once.

Comment: If any of these options help you, let me know and I will update my answer.

Comment: I have come to the same conclusion as you. I need to dynamically add new `<input type="file">` fields to the form, and send the whole form at once. I even do not need any plug-ins. Thanks!

Comment: Btw, I still have to use `move_uploaded_file()` to process it ot I can just work with it in a tmp dir?

Comment: You can read the file from the tmp folder directly, you don't have to move it, the advantage is that PHP will delete it when the script ends.